# Magnet tilt - null point relation

Tags: magnetic-fields

Apparently, if a bar magnet held in a horizontal plane on earth is rotated by any angle $\theta$, the null points of the magnetic field rotate by $\frac{\theta}{2}$.

My professor just explained this using an example of rotating it by 180° from a position parallel to the magnetic field lines of the earth.

Can somebody provide the mathematical proof for this?

Edit: Null points are points where the resultant magnetic field is zero (it's cancelled out by the Earth's magnetic field.)

Comment: 1. what do you call  null points of the magnetic field ?

Comment: Edited it to add that.

Answer (score -1):

if  the resultant magnetic field is zero in one direction, it will never be zero in any other direction. But the resulting magnetic field is in the direction of half the angle of rotation . if you ad two forces of the same magnitude, the resulting force is always half between them.Just draw two forces , and add then, than you can see it.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? How can a resultant magnetic field be zero **in one direction?**

Comment: sorry, with direction I meant the direction of the bar magnet. so if the magnetic field of the earth and that of the bar magnet cancel each other, this can only happen with one direction of the bar magnet.